# Is it true that $\mathbb{E}|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|=0$ where $\mathbb{E}(X) $ is finite?

Tags: probability, expected-value, means

I'm not sure

1. whether this is always true? and
2. If it is true, whether it is a trivial assertion to make?

I've tried integrating using the definition of expectation, but I'm not getting anywhere with it.

Comment: Make a case decision: $X\geq \mathbb E(X)$ and $X< \mathbb E(X)$

Comment: @EuxhenH ok so you are still able to take the mean outside of the absolute value sign still?

Comment: Try an example, such as $X$ being $+1$ or $-1$ each with probability $\frac12$

Answer (score 3):

It is true if and only if $X$ is a constant random  variable. Reason: $|X-\mathbb E X|$  is  non-negative random variable and its expectation can be $0$ only when it is zero almost surely.